# Is there any way to open "Windows Mobility Center" using java?

Tags: java, windows

I think that most of you have heard about the "Windows Mobility Center".
That's the app by windows that can change volume, brightness etc.

I'm trying to ask you is there any way to open that "Windows Mobility Center"
using Java code?

Thanks for answers, sorry if I was unspecific.

Comment: stackoverflow is the wrong network for thi kind of questions

Comment: Okay, ill try to find some other place to get the answer. -Thanks

Comment: also: probably you can't since all java programs run in a virtual machine

Answer (score 2):

Windows Mobility Center can be found in `C:\Windows\System32\`
So you just need to run this cmd command: `C:\Windows\System32\mblctr.exe`

It should work like this: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\mblctr.exe")`